# PyMongo failing to update MongoDB due to transactions

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, transactions, pymongo

I have no real experience with Python or MongoDB, but I'm using [this script](https://github.com/user578/gridfsmigrate/blob/af819b25b4519e84b02979e0e2745c3a7e3bc728/migrate.py) to migrate some files from the database.
An error occurs when the `update_one` command runs on line 190:

`collection.update_one({"_id": dbId}, {"$set": update_data})`

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Transaction numbers are only allowed on storage engines that support document-level locking`

It seems to be because it's trying to use transactions, and as we only have one MongoDB it won't support transactions (from what I've read).

I've checked the variables used on the line and they all seem fine, so now I'm a bit stuck.

Ideally I'm hoping there's a way to say "don't use transactions" when you connect to the DB. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Further info:

`# python3 -V
Python 3.6.8`

`# mongod --version
db version v4.0.10
git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64`

Comment: Two questions: 1) Which version of PyMongo? 2) Which storage engine are you using ? you can find out from `mongo` shell by running `db.serverStatus().storageEngine`

Comment: Pymongo V3.9.0 and "mmapv1" for the storage engine. Thanks for adding how to find that out!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the collection name from csv at line [164](https://github.com/user578/gridfsmigrate/blob/af819b25b4519e84b02979e0e2745c3a7e3bc728/migrate.py#L164) and collection is assigned at line [172](https://github.com/user578/gridfsmigrate/blob/af819b25b4519e84b02979e0e2745c3a7e3bc728/migrate.py#L172). You are trying to update doc at line [190](https://github.com/user578/gridfsmigrate/blob/af819b25b4519e84b02979e0e2745c3a7e3bc728/migrate.py#L190).

Atomic update of two collections is effectively a transaction. MongoDB did not support transactions across collections or even within a collection until version 3.6, from version 4.0 they add support for transactions. You should use transactions for multi collection update. Look at the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) examples to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [PyMongo v3.9.0](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-3-9-0) and uses MongoDB with the [MMAPv1 storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/mmapv1/), you must explicitly disable [retryable writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/) to avoid running into [pymongo.errors.OperationFailure](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.OperationFailure) exceptions during write operations. You can disable this with either:

- Via the connection string e.g. MongoClient("mongodb://my.mongodb.cluster/db?retryWrites=false")
- Via the [MongoClient](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) constructor’s keyword argument e.g. MongoClient("mongodb://my.mongodb.cluster/db", retryWrites=False)

This is because MMAPv1 storage engine is deprecated and also does not support `retryable` writes which are now turned on by default since PyMongo v3.9.0.

I'd recommend to also upgrade/switch your MongoDB server to use [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger) (Default since MongoDB v3.2, and will be removed starting MongoDB v4.2). For tutorial on how to change the storage engine, please see:

- [Change a standalone MongoDB to WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-standalone-wiredtiger/)
- [Change a replica set MongoDB to WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-replica-set-wiredtiger/)